# Como visualizar através do breakpoint quais valores foram passados para o meu método?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Gostaria de saber se é possível sem usar o `Debug.WriteLine` visualizar os valores passados para o meu método através do Visual studio utilizando um BreakPoint, seja por algum recurso externo ou não.

Comment: Eai, jovem. A resposta atendeu o que você precisava?

Comment: Atendeu sim LINQ, desculpa a demora para marcar como correta ! Obrigado c: +1 para ti(como sempre mandando boas respostas).

Comment: De boa, eu sei que você já é experiente no site e sabe como usá-lo, então nem fico grilado com a não-aceitação. Eu só queria saber se eu realmente tinha entendido bem a tua pergunta. Enfim, que bom que consegui te ajudar =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só pôr um ponto de interrupção (*breakpoint*) no método e passar o mouse sobre os parâmetros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou colocar as variáveis na janela *watch*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]